# R convert a text rows to dat frame

Tags: r

How do I convert the below R input to dat frame in the mentioned format

R code

```
input <- suppressWarnings(readLines(stdin(), n=10))
2 3
800 2
1 200
2 400
1200 2
1 400
3 600
300
400
500
```

Expected format

[image]
**Input Explanation**

**line 1[x,y]**  - > **x** (2) denoting total number of executives and **y** (3) denoting total number of overall properties among all executives

After that all lines based on each executives iteration

**line 2[x,y]** - > **x** Cp of the overall properties for that executive and **y** total lease property presence of that executive

**line3,4[x,y]**  -> Lease of that Executive subsequent properties

Again same process repeat for 2nd executive from line 5

finally **line  8 to 10** - > cost price of individual properties

Any tips or suggestion to start on this..

Comment: I do not understand the logic. could you please clarify?

Comment: How does the data look like, if there are three or more executives?

Comment: @Martin for each executive.. each row is added.

Comment: @Tarje. Which part you want me to explain.